# How to calculate interdaily stability for signal in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, signal-processing

I'm trying to calculate interdaily stability as a feature for machine learning classification in Python. My data is for multiple days - I'm using [this dataset](https://datasets.simula.no/depresjon/) ([sample CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/178bPs9fkm2OmelhBOmNEv3Go0rDPmQOL/view?usp=sharing)). This data is sampled with minute frequency, i.e. we have 60 measurements per hour. The formula is:
[image]

So my approach is:

```
def interdaily_stability(df: pd.DataFrame) -> float:
    X_mean = df["activity"].mean()

    hourly_means = df.resample("H", on="timestamp").mean()["activity"].values
    p = len(hourly_means)

    numerator = (1/p) * np.sum(np.square((hourly_means - X_mean)))
    denominator = df["activity"].var()

    return numerator / denominator
```

1. Is this formula right? In particular, is `p` right?
2. In particular, am I calculating this right for multiple days? If not, how can I correct this?

I know that [pyActigraphy](https://github.com/ghammad/pyActigraphy) exists, but the implementation there seems incorrect for my case, e.g. there data is first resampled with `.resample("1H").sum()`, and then grouped by by hour, minute and second (I don't even have such resolution).

I also tried translating the code from `nparACT` library in R, but I don't know R good enough: [nparACT implementation](https://github.com/cran/nparACT/blob/master/R/nparACT_ISIVfunctions.R).

Comment: Please do not tag R if you want an answer in python

Comment: …and when you're using pandas and dataframes, **do** tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your implementation is correct, as i am also trying to quantify the rest-activity rhythm and using calculated score, how feasible is Modelling that time series or not.

After, exploration, could simplify **Interdaily stability** quantifies how consistent the activity patterns are, given over a period of time.

```
def interdaily_stability(df: pd.DataFrame,activity_col) -> float:

'''
Interdaily stability was centered and normalized by 
subtracting the overall mean and dividing by the overall 
standard deviation.

ref: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4542004/
'''

# Calculating Mean of the OP Signal
X_mean = df[activity_col].mean()
# Converting to hourly format and computing mean per hour
hourly_means = df.resample("H", on="timestamp").mean()[activity_col].values
# Capturing number of hours we have in our dataset
p = len(hourly_means)
# Centering and normalizing by subtracting the overall mean
numerator = (1/p) * np.sum(np.square((hourly_means - X_mean)))
# Overall standard deviation
denominator = df[activity_col].var()

return numerator / denominator
```

The article mentioned in the docstring is the one that simplifies the equation a but.

Actual equation looks like this:
[image]

This is a work in progress.